# Let's brain-storm a site-theme for inspirations!!!1

Tags: discussion, design

Hello fellow Ethereum Stack-Exchangers!

It will take probably a looong time till we see first proposals for a new site-wide theme for Ethereum Stack Exchange! However, it would be nice if we could gather **inspirations** from the Ethereum community.

Anything is allowed in this thread. From posting professional templates which will probably not used to any cute cat-with-diamond pictures for inspiration.

[image: my initial draft]

Use the tools you are most comfortable with, and don't waste too much time. Please, make sure to elaborate, **why** you think your post/picture/template is important in your eyes for this design-inspirational sprint. :)

---

Edit: Yearly bump-y-bump (2021) - we are still the **most active** StackExchange site without a custom design. :(

Comment: Yes it may be a long time.  The graduation of Vehicle Mechanics was announced almost exactly a year ago and it still hasn't issued a draft theme - https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1915/6299

Comment: I raised that (again) on Meta: [When will a graduated site get a theme or custom branding?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368463/when-will-a-graduated-site-get-a-theme-or-custom-branding)

Comment: A relevant post (on this meta) by one of our designers from yesterday: [Custom Ethereum design and logo - Information gathering](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/q/697/79828) :)