# Why doesn't Ethereum Stack Exchange have an Ethereum icon?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Just a detail but it would definitely look good and differentiate from the generic initials bubble for stackexchange boards.

Comment: Related: [Meta: Let's brain-storm a site-theme for inspirations!!!1](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/530/lets-brain-storm-a-site-theme-for-inspirations1)

Comment: Also related: https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/474/congratulations-ethereum-is-graduating

Comment: Definitely agree. A complete design theme is a bigger undertaking but I am sure it would be simple to replace the favicon (displayed in browser tab title, and elsewhere on the site) from just **ETH** to Ethereum's "diamond icon" (for want of a better name. Maybe there is a better name that I do not know yet :-)

Answer (score 5):

Right now (and for the last couple of years) all of the site designs have been held up in queue. We're waiting to release anything new until we've rolled out the [responsive design update to all of the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314979/rollout-of-responsive-design-site-themes-tracking-post). All of the sites with the default/beta blue theme will get the update soon, though I'm not sure when. You can see what it will look like by going over to [PP&CG](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Once the backlog from updating all of the existing sites' designs is handled, we'll be able to turn our eye towards creating new site designs for all of the network sites that are waiting on them, including Ethereum. We don't have a specific order in mind but some sites have been waiting close to three years, so please give us some time to get through that list. I'm guessing that site age or graduation date will play into this to a degree.

Let me know if you have any questions. I'm not on the design team (I'm one of the Community Managers - HI!) but I know some stuff and can ask about other things.

Comment: Hi Catjia, thanks for stopping by and keeping us posted :)